# iDangerous Swiper - hide navigation arrows from first and last slide

Tags: jquery, navigation, slider, hide

Using [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php) how do you target and hide the .left-arrow class of the first slide? There is this in the documentation - mySwiper.getFirstSlide() - returns first slider slide (slide instance) but how do you indicate that when on this slide hide the left arrow?

Not handy with js but I've tried things like this with no success:

```
mySwiper.getFirstSlide({
  $(this).find('.left-arrow').hide(),
});

var firstSlide = mySwiper.getFirstSlide();
firstSlide.find('.left-arrow').hide();
```

This probably needs to be a conditional statement - if it's the first slide then hide the left arrow else show it. I'm just not sure how to set something like that up. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

http://codepen.io/NewbCake/pen/sIbxi

Answer (score 6):

It's much easier than you think, specially if you're not handy with JS, considering you could solve this with pure CSS.

Swiper assigns a CSS class named ".swiper-button-disabled" to the first and last arrow, to make sure the swiper doesn´t move any further. Try this:

```
.left-arrow.swiper-button-disabled {opacity: 0;}
```

Comment: Apparently it does so only beginning from 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
var howManySlides = $('.swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide').length - 1;
$(".arrow-left").addClass('hide');
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    loop:false,
    onSlideChangeStart: function(){
        $(".tabs .arrow-left,.tabs .arrow-left").removeClass('hide');
        if(tabsSwiper.activeIndex === 0) {
            $(".tabs .arrow-left").addClass('hide');
        }
        if(tabsSwiper.activeIndex === howManySlides) {
            $(".tabs .arrow-right").addClass('hide');
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it may work as you want if i did understand the question right:

```
  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    loop:false,

  })
  $('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
     $('.arrow-right').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.arrow-right').show();
    },3000);
    mySwiper.swipePrev();
  });
  $('.arrow-right').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.arrow-left').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.arrow-left').show();
    },3000);
    mySwiper.swipeNext();
  });
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Sorry I may have not been entirely clear. I'm trying to always hide the left arrow only on the first slide. As well as the hide right arrow only on the last slide. All the slides in between should have both arrows.

Comment: Ah Okay now i get it.. two secs :)

Comment: Any luck? Is the way to approach this to get the length of the slides then hide the left-arrow slide if the slide in the array is equal to 0?

Answer (score 0):

For `ionic`
In controller assigned to `ion-content` containing `ion-slides`
add slider to scope:

```
 $scope.$on("$ionicSlides.sliderInitialized", function (event, data) {
            // data.slider is the instance of Swiper
            $scope.mySlider = data.slider;
        });
```

add hiding/inactivating css class like:

```
.inactive-my-button {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

apply class on buttons with proper condition - here my buttons placed in footer just after `</ion-slides>`

```
<ion-footer-bar >
    <div class="buttons" 
         ng-click="mySlider.slidePrev()" 
         ng-class="{'inactive-my-button': (mySlider.activeIndex == 0)}">
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <div class="buttons" 
         ng-click="mySlider.slideNext()" 
         ng-class="{'inactive-my-button': (mySlider.activeIndex == mySlider.slides.length-1)}">
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```